# Better Solution for making a HTML table outta multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, html-table

```
 /**
 * Assoziatives Array in einer Tabelle ausgeben mit Bootstrap Styles
 * @param $array Das Array
 * @param $style Optional: Platz für weitere Stylings, default = 'table-hover table-condensed'
 */ 
public function assoc_array_to_table($arr, $style ='table-hover table-condensed'){

    // Neue Tabelle erstellen und Standartstyling vergeben
    echo "<table class='table " . $style . "'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    // Nimmt die Keys vom ersten äußeren Array
    $keys = array_keys($arr[0]); //vorname, nachname, titel, etc...
    // Verteilt die Keys als Überschriften
    foreach($keys as $key){
        echo "<th>". $key ."</th>";
    }
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach($arr as $arr2) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($arr2 as $value){
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

This code converts a multidimensional array to an HTML table.

I tried a lot and also worked with my brother, but he is not able to understand the code, so...

I need a cleaner and shorter code for my solution. Any advice?

This is how the table looks like currently:
[image: Current table setup]

Comment: Is there an actual problem with the code, or you just want it shorter? It looks reasonably concise to me already, building tables looks like this in my experience. You can certainly make it shorter but you'd be sacrificing readability.

Comment: there is no problem actually i just would like to see how a solution would look like from a experienced programmer to getting better and learn from it.

Comment: do you understand what the code above is doing?

Comment: I didnt knew about CodeReview but thank you all for your time. If a migration to CodeReview work, i'd like to have this.

Answer (score 0):

The code works well and isn't *that* long, so i don't really see a need to make it shorter.

But one way to make it *a bit* shorter would be to erase all comments and merge some of the echoed strings into one string:

```html
public function assoc_array_to_table($arr, $style ='table-hover table-condensed'){
    echo "<table class='table ".$style."'><thead>";
    $keys = array_keys($arr[0]); //vorname, nachname, titel, etc...
    foreach($keys as $key){
        echo "<th>".$key."</th>";
    }
    echo "</thead><tbody>";
    foreach($arr as $arr2) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($arr2 as $value){
            echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
```